# Embedded image in HTML signature works in Lotus Notes 9 but not 8.5

Tags: php, lotus-notes

We have a corporate signature that I am making a tool in PHP webform to automatically generate the file.  I been using Lotus Notes 9 myself and it seems to work fine.  However, the folks that still use Notes 8.5, the image file comes back broken.  The image is already on the server where it converts it to base64 and plops it directly into the img tag.

```
$imgPath   = "/opt/intranet/signature/images/";
$imgFile   = "logo.png";
$data      = file_get_contents($imgPath . $imgFile);
$base      = base64_encode($data);
$image     = 'data:image/png;base64,'.$base;
$logo01    = "<p><img src=\"$image\" alt=\"corp logo\" />";
```

And I really cannot figure out if there is a coding issue for embedded graphics or Lotus setting that needs to be changed.  The HTML file it generates works regardless.

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base64 embedded images don't work in Notes Client 8.5 HTML signature.

Use an URL for img src. It doesn't matter if it's "file://..." or a "http://...". The picture will always be embedded in mail body.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of.  If I use file and have it on the corporate LAN, would the image then not show up to the recipient?  Or I can force the marketing folks to host the image on the actual web server.

Comment: The picture will be *embedded* in mail body at mail creation time. So, the recipient don't need access to original image source.

Comment: Main issue is, the folks in the "field" don't have access to intranet,it needs VPN.  Email doesn't need VPN.  The corporate website may work, but it is on an IIS server and it is prone to failure, thus I had hoped the embedded solution would had worked, but since that only works in v9, I will have to talk to marketing and see what he proposes.  In the past I think we just copied/pasted the graphic from within a word document but that enabled smart quotes which broke other systems.  Is there a way to say save the graph, embed it into an RTF file, would Notes 8.5+ then allow it to work better?

Comment: I think creating a RichText signature could solve it. You would work with the NotesRichTextItem class and add an inline picture like shown here: http://www.grange.com.br/posts/lotusscript-code-to-embed-a-picture-into-a-notes-richtext-item/

Comment: I found a a PHPRtfLite library that I am going to play with.  It seems like it can do the trick with making the file.  Any advantage of using the Lotus Script instead?  Danke

Comment: If you can get it to work with PHPRtfLite then it's fine as long as the user creating email has access to file at this moment. The advantage of RichText approach is that the image is already included and there is no need to access a file at email creation time anymore. The example is written in LotusScript but you can use the Notes classes in other languages too.